# Springboot "Circular view path" and "Error resolving Template"

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement JWT with a little page and I had the problem "Circular view path". I read that it could be solved with spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf, but then i got the "Error resolving Template"

**UserController**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
private UserRepository userRep;
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


public UserController (UserRepository applicationUserRepository,
                      BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userRep = applicationUserRepository;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

// Especificamos el endpoint para realizar el registro, y el parámetro
// necesario (tipo Usuario) que debe de estar completamente formado
@RequestMapping(value = "/registraUsuario", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void registraUsuario (@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
    usuario.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(usuario.getPassword()));
    userRep.save(usuario);
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
   public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {
   Usuario findByEmail(String mail);
}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
private UserRepository applicationUserRepository;

public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
    this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Usuario applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByEmail(mail);
    if (applicationUser == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(mail);
    }
    return new User(applicationUser.getEmail(), applicationUser.getPassword(), emptyList());
   }
}
```

Any idea. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It seems problem was that UserController had @RequestMapping(value = "/registraUsuario", and it was the same as SIGN_UP_URL in SecurityConstants file

```
public class SecurityConstants {
    public static final String SECRET = "SecretKeyToGenJWTs";
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
    // Cabeceras para probar con el postman
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Permiso";
    // Aquí iría la URL donde se registra el ususario en nuestra página
    public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/registraUsuario";
}
```

And that was creating the loop. I have changed name of SIGN_UP_URL = "/usuario/registraUsuario", and added the @RequestMapping("/usuario") to the userController, and now there is no problem. So finally, this is the final code for those two files that i have changed

**UserController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UserController {
    private UserRepository userRep;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


    public UserController (UserRepository applicationUserRepository,
                          BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userRep = applicationUserRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    // Especificamos el endpoint para realizar el registro, y el parámetro
    // necesario (tipo Usuario) que debe de estar completamente formado
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registraUsuario", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void registraUsuario (@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
        usuario.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(usuario.getPassword()));
        userRep.save(usuario);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConstants**

```
public class SecurityConstants {
    public static final String SECRET = "SecretKeyToGenJWTs";
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
    // Cabeceras para probar con el postman
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Permiso";
    // Aquí iría la URL donde se registra el ususario en nuestra página
    public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/usuario/registraUsuario";
}
```

Hope this helps.